# Paste in VSCode for certain number of times

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to copy part of a text and paste it for certain number of times in visual studio code?

Comment: I saw someone use this in his lecture. I wonder how does he do it. 
https://youtu.be/zFZrkCIc2Oc?t=5739

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any technique or package in VSCode, but I found a package in Sublime called `PasteRepeater` which does exactly what I wanted.